# Distributing dlls: What to do with .lib files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker

I have created a `dll` using C# in Visual Studio. It has six `.lib` files in its dependencies.

From reading some other questions on here, I have gathered that `.lib` files are linked at runtime, which makes me think that those files are not included in the `.dll` file I make.

How can I distribute the `dll` file, then? Will I have to send the `.lib` files along with the `.dll` file, or is there some way to compile it statically so that everything is included in the one `.dll` file?

Comment: .NET does not have a linking phase. How are you using the `.lib` files?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn To be very precise, the C# project references a C++ project, which in turn depends on those six libraries (through the `Additional Dependencies` option).

Comment: Output of the C++ project will contain code for those six libraries embedded into it. Because .lib files are statically linked. What's the output of that C++ project? And is that a C++/CLI project?

Comment: It is an unmanaged C++ project that outputs a `.dll` file as well.

Comment: I don't think you will need to include the libs. Just the C++ dll would suffice. Try running your final output without including the lib files and see if you get any error.  You would need to include that C++ dll file too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see which files should be distributed with the DLL, you can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Just drag your DLL file to the application and see if it has any dependencies.

Also note that you might need to distribute the Visual C++ Runtime ("Visual C++ Redistributable Package").

Comment: @kshahar Could you please elaborate on that last bit? I am testing right now, and it seems that my C# dll is complaining because it can not find the C++ dll. This might be because I didn't add a reference to the latter, but well, that seems to be impossible in Visual Studio. ("A reference to Foo.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.")

Answer (score 1):

For C# you won't need to include any .lib files.
They are used by the C/C++ compiler at the linking step, but C# uses the DLL **without** linking (dynamic load and `GetProcAddress`) with the `[DLLImport()]` attribute.

You'll be fine just distributing the DLLs with your application.